# Performance issues of #pragma omp atomic with OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic, pragma, single-threaded

I have observed an unexpected (for me!) behavior of an openmp code which I am writing. The code structure is the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){ 
 // lots of calculations that produce 3 integers i1,i2,i3 and 3 doubles d1,d2,d3 
 #pragma omp atomic 
 J1[i1] += d1;
 #pragma omp atomic
 J2[i2] += d2; 
 #pragma omp atomic
 J3[i3] += d3; 
}
```

I have compiled three different versions of this code:

1) with openmp (-fopenmp)

2) without openmp

3) with openmp, but without the 3 atomic operations (just as a test, since atomic operations are necessary)

When I run version 1) with environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS=1, I observe a significant slowdown with respect to version 2); while version 3) runs as fast as version 2).

I would like to know the reason for this behavior (why do atomic operations slow the code down even if single-threded?!) and if it is possible to compile/rewrite the code in such a way that version 1) runs as fast as version 2).

I attach at the end of the question a working example which shows the aforementioned behavior. I compiled 1) with:

```
g++ -fopenmp -o toy_code toy_code.cpp -std=c++11 -O3
```

2) with:

```
g++ -o toy_code_NO_OMP toy_code.cpp -std=c++11 -O3
```

and 3) with:

```
g++ -fopenmp -o toy_code_NO_ATOMIC toy_code_NO_ATOMIC.cpp -std=c++11 -O3
```

The version of the compiler is gcc version 5.3.1 20160519 (Debian 5.3.1-20).
The execution time of the 3 versions is:

1) 1 min 24 sec

2) 51 sec

3) 51 sec

Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
// toy_code.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#define Np 1000000
#define N 1000

int main (){
        double* Xp, *Yp, *J,*Jb;
        Xp = new double[Np];
        Yp = new double[Np];  
        J = new double [N*N];
        Jb = new double [N*N];

        for(int i=0;i<N*N;i++){
            J[i]=0.0;
            Jb[i]=0.0;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<Np;i++){
            Xp[i] = rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX - 0.5;
            Yp[i] = rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX - 0.5;
        }

        for(int n=0; n<2000; n++){
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int p=0;p<Np;p++){
            double rx = (Xp[p]+0.5)*(N-1);
            double ry = (Yp[p]+0.5)*(N-1);
            int xindex = (int)floor(rx+0.5);
            int yindex = (int)floor(ry+0.5);
            int k;
            k=xindex*N+yindex;

            #pragma omp atomic
            J[k]+=1;
            #pragma omp atomic
            Jb[k]+=1;
         }
         }

        delete[] Xp;
        delete[] Yp;
        delete[] J;
        delete[] Jb;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: with openmp enabled, pragmas are expanded to GOMP code that probably induces overhead compared to sequential code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable OpenMP, gcc has to generate different code that works for any number of threads that is only known at runtime.

In this particular case take a look at output of `gcc -S` (slightly shortened by lables).

Without OpenMP:

```
.loc 1 38 0 discriminator 2  # Line 38 is J[k]+=1;
movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm1
cvttsd2si   %xmm0, %edx
cvttsd2si   %xmm1, %eax
movsd   .LC3(%rip), %xmm0
imull   $1000, %eax, %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
cltq
salq    $3, %rax
leaq    0(%r13,%rax), %rdx
.loc 1 40 0 discriminator 2   # Line 40 is Jb[k]+=1;
addq    %r12, %rax
.loc 1 29 0 discriminator 2
cmpq    $8000000, %r15
.loc 1 38 0 discriminator 2
addsd   (%rdx), %xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, (%rdx)
.loc 1 40 0 discriminator 2
movsd   .LC3(%rip), %xmm0
addsd   (%rax), %xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, (%rax)
```

The loop is unrolled making this rather complicated.

With `-fopenmp`:

```
movsd   (%rsp), %xmm2
cvttsd2si   %xmm0, %eax
cvttsd2si   %xmm2, %ecx
imull   $1000, %ecx, %ecx
addl    %eax, %ecx
movslq  %ecx, %rcx
salq    $3, %rcx
movq    %rcx, %rsi
addq    16(%rbp), %rsi
movq    (%rsi), %rdx
movsd   8(%rsp), %xmm1
jmp .L4
movq    %rax, %rdx
movq    %rdx, (%rsp)
movq    %rdx, %rax
movsd   (%rsp), %xmm3
addsd   %xmm1, %xmm3
movq    %xmm3, %rdi
lock cmpxchgq   %rdi, (%rsi)
cmpq    %rax, %rdx
jne .L9
.loc 1 40 0
addq    24(%rbp), %rcx
movq    (%rcx), %rdx
jmp .L5
.p2align 4,,10
.p2align 3
movq    %rax, %rdx
movq    %rdx, (%rsp)
movq    %rdx, %rax
movsd   (%rsp), %xmm4
addsd   %xmm1, %xmm4
movq    %xmm4, %rsi
lock cmpxchgq   %rsi, (%rcx)
cmpq    %rax, %rdx
jne .L10
addq    $8, %r12
cmpq    %r12, %rbx
jne .L6
```

I'm not going to try to explain or understand all the details of what is happening here, but thats not necessary for the message: The compiler has to use different atomic instructions that are likely more costly, especially `lock cmpxchgq`.

Besides this fundamental issue, OpenMP may mess with the optimizer in any imaginable way, e.g. interfer with unrolling. I've also seen a curious case where the intel compiler actually generates more efficient serial code for an OpenMP loop.

P.S. Consider yourself lucky - it could be much worse. If the compiler cannot map the atomic instruction to a hardware instruction, it has to use locks which would be even slower.

Comment: To avoid the problem I added an if statement to check the number of threads so that in the case of single thread the code is serial, without any pragma directive. Thank you.