# Why "#pragma omp atomic" increase runtime when using omp_num_threads is 1?

Tags: c, openmp, openmpi

I am learning how to use OpenMP in C program. I noticed that "#pragma omp atomic" will increase the runtime even if the number of threads is 1 while updating a 1d array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>

double fixwork(int a, int n) //n==L
{
    int j;
    double s, x, y;
    double t = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        s = 1.0 * j * a;
        x = (1.0 - cos(s)) / 2.0;
        y = 0.31415926 * x; 
        t += y;
    }

    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 100000;
    int p = 1;
    int L = 2;
    int q = 100;
    int g = 7;
    int i, j, k;
    double v;

    int np, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    
    double* u = (double*)calloc(n * g, sizeof(double));
    double* w = (double*)calloc(n * g, sizeof(double));
    
    double omptime1 = -MPI_Wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for private(k, j, v) num_threads(p)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        k = i * (int)ceil(1.0 * (i % q) / q);
        for (j = 0; j < g; j++)
        {
            v = fixwork(i * g + j, L);
#pragma omp atomic 
            u[k] += v;
        }
    }
    omptime1 += MPI_Wtime();
    
    printf("\npragma time = %f", omptime1);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I complied this code by:

```
mpiicc -qopenmp atomictest.c -o atomic
```

With 1 openmp thread and 1 mpi process, the observed ratio of time(use atomic)/time(no atomic) is ~ 1.28 (n=1e6), ~1.07 (n=1e7), and even larger for smaller n. It says the atomic directive itself has cost more time to operate. What is the reason for such performance? What is the difference between the machine operations of "omp atomic" and "c++ atomic"?
Thanks

Comment: Comparing execution times of unoptimized code is not worth the time. What differences do you get when optimizing (with `-O3`)? Do you get different performance using `std::atomic` (since you mention it in your question, although you've tagged this as C)?

Comment: As a matter fo general style, please, please, please, declare your variables in their minimal scope. That has been legal in C since at least C99 (so for over 20 years). It makes it easier for other people (and the compiler) to understand the code, and often avoids bugs when you parallelise with OpenMP, since you don't need to add `private` declarations for variables which are declared inside what becomes the parallel region.

Answer (score 1):

It is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573265/performance-issues-of-pragma-omp-atomic-with-omp-num-threads-1):

> If you enable OpenMP, gcc has to generate different code that works
> for any number of threads that is only known at runtime..... The
> compiler has to use different atomic instructions that are likely more
> costly...